# Xtext pass parameter to variable

Tags: xtext

I have an example DSL with some `UserDefinition` and some "action definitions" and I'm trying to realize some macro like function. Here is the grammar so far:

```
UserDefinition:
    'User' name=ID
    '{'
    features+=Feature*
    '}'
;

Feature:
    name=ID '=' value=STRING
;

EnterTextAction: 
    'enter text' ref=[UserDefinition] 'into' targetElement=TargetElement
;
```

with this (and additionally some scoping) I can create users and let them execute the action with:

```
User admin{
     username="root"
     password="passwd"
}

enter admin.username into Username
enter admin.password into Password
```

But now I want to create a macro like fuction to do something like:

```
Macro login {
    data = user
    enter user.username into Username
    enter user.password into Password
}

run login using admin
```

Which should execute the single actions later in the generated code. 
For this I created the rules:

```
Macro:
    'macro' name=ID '{'
    data=Data
    actions+=EnterTextAction*
    '}'
;

RunMacroInteraction:
    'run' macro=[Macro] 'using' user=[Userdefinition]
;

Data:
    name=ID '=' userdef=Userdefinition
;
```

So my question is: How can I pass the user (reference) in the `RunMacroInteraction` call as a parameter and assign it to the name defined in Macro.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An Xtext DSL isn't an interpreter; it's a *parser*. An Xtext DSL just gives you the tools to parse some text into a model. In your case, the model should probably lists of `RunMacroInteraction`:

```
Model : scripts=RunMacroInteraction* ;
```

In your interpreter, you first set up the Xtext environment. Now you can call the parser to get a `Model`. After that, you can examine the model. For example, you can call a method for each `RunMacroInteraction` in `Model.getScripts()`. In that method, you can get the macro name, look it up in the model and then call another method which executes the commands in the macro with the arguments you found.

Comment: so there is no way to tell the Model that the user inside the `Macro` "login" is just a reference to the `UserDefinition` "admin" defined elsewhere?

Comment: That's what the `[]` do for you. So you already have that. Just look at the Java code which Xtext generates for you.

Comment: Yeah but my basic question is, how to assign that reference to a different variable (or name) like in Java `int a = 42; int b = a` where a and b are 42. I thought the `{UserDefinition}` notation will create a new instance, but I do not know how to assign the reference to that new instance. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: For a last time: Look at the generated code. `RunMacroInteraction.getUser()` returns an instance of `Userdefinition`. Now for `data = user` (first line of your Macro in the DSL): You will have to write code to implement a local variable scope for this. If you use `userdef=[Userdefinition]`, then you will get the value for free from the model.